# Disable sorting in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to disable sorting in jqGrid for all columns instead of adding `sortable: false` to each column in colModel?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This functionality was added in jqGrid 4.0+

After defining your colModel section in the jqGrid configuration, add the following:

```
cmTemplate: {sortable:false},
```

This will force all columns to no longer be sortable.

Comment: I wanted to write the same. Thanks! The feature `cmTemplate` exists already in jqGrid 3.8.2, but the priority of `cmTemplate` was too high in 3.8.2. So if you use `cmTemplate: {sortable:false}` and have `sortable:true` in some column, the jqGrid 3.8.2 will use `sortable:false` for all columns and jqGrid 4.x will do use the setting `sortable:true` for one column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to conditionally disable sorting on all columns rather than hardcoding it in your grid then I would recommend the following

```
//your function
function Example(){

    //define grid
    var grid  = $("#list");

    //get all column names
    var columnNames = grid[0].p.colNames;

    //iterate through each and disable
    for (i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
          grid.setColProp(columnNames[i], { sortable: false });
        }
  }
```