# Does the jqGrid sortable option allow the user to sort grid or does it allow column reordering?

Tags: jqgrid

I set sort to true and datatype per column for sorting. I need to turn sorting off but allow column reordering. Does the jqGrid sortable option allow the user to sort the grid, reorder columns or is it some combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really many misunderstandnesses about the [jqGrid option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) `sortable: true`. It's the option which means only the reordering of columns by by dragging and dropping of the column headers.

On the other side all columns of jqGrid can be sorted by default. There are `sortable` property in `colModel` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)) which is responsible for sorting of column. The default value of the property is `sortable: true`. If you need do deny sorting in some columns you have to place `sortable: false` in the definition of the corresponding column in `colModel`. If you have more non-sortable columns (or if you want to have all columns not-sortable) then you can change default value of `sortable` property in `colModel` by usage

```js
cmTemplate: { sortable: false }
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148525/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details.